Getting error when sending second message "Error : TypeError: chatMessage._getType is not a function"
I encountered this error after upgrading Langchain.js to a new Version 0.1.35 . I am using HNSWLib Vector Store
Full stack trace :
TypeError: chatMessage._getType is not a function
at /home/apsara/llm_node/langchain_Version2/node_modules/langchain/dist/chains/conversational_retrieval_chain.cjs:139:33
at Array.map ()
at Function.getChatHistoryString (/home/apsara/llm_node/langchain_Version2/node_modules/langchain/dist/chains/conversational_retrieval_chain.cjs:138:18)
at ConversationalRetrievalQAChain._call (/home/apsara/llm_node/langchain_Version2/node_modules/langchain/dist/chains/conversational_retrieval_chain.cjs:162:60)
at ConversationalRetrievalQAChain.invoke (/home/apsara/llm_node/langchain_Version2/node_modules/langchain/dist/chains/base.cjs:67:24)
at async LMMService.call (/home/apsara/llm_node/langchain_Version2/src/api/services/lmm.service.ts:240:23)
at async LLMController.call (/home/apsara/llm_node/langchain_Version2/src/api/controllers/LLMController.ts:47:30)
